# Gutenberg InnerBlocks allowed types and reusable blocks

Tags: block-editor

I have the parent block `example/parent` that contains

```
<InnerBlocks
  allowedBlocks={['example/children']}
  template={template}
/>
```

And the child block `example/children` with

```
registerBlockType('example/children', {
  apiVersion: 2,
  ...

  parent: ['example/parent'],
```

All works as expected, but if I create reusable block from a children, it can not be inserted in any other parent again, the `[+]` icon will automatically create new block without the option to choose a reusable block. Is there a way to enable allowedBlocks `example/children` or reusable block of type `example/children` ?

**Edit (more details)**

I have the case of parent - children blocks, and inside the parent block `InnerBlocks` should be allowed both the children block and reusable blocks (preferable created from the `example/children`)

Comment: reusable blocks are blocks of type `core/block`, the post technically isn't aware of sub-blocks as the contents of a `core/block` belong to another post. I had to re-readd your last paragraph several times though and I'm still unsure what it's trying to put across, but I'm guessiing that you'r asking why you can't insert a reusable block inside your custom block when you've used `alllowedBlocks`? Or have I miisunderstood? Can you edit the question to explain in a different clearer way that's less ambiguous?

Comment: Yes,
"why you can't insert a reusable block inside your custom block when you've used alllowedBlocks?"
This is what I am trying to get

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, "why you can't insert a reusable block inside your custom block when you've used alllowedBlocks?" This is what I am trying to get

This is because you haven't allowed them:

```
allowedBlocks={['example/children']}
```

The list of allowed blocks does not include reusable blocks ( `core/block` ), so they are not allowed and cannot be inserted. Add `core/block` to the list to fix that.

Remember, a reusable block is a block of type `core/block`, its content belongs to another post entirely. If you say only `example/children` blocks are allowed, this does not mean a reusable block that contains `example/children` can be inserted, because a reusable block is of type `core/block` and has no inner blocks. You only see inner blocks in the editor because the UI is being helpful and showing you the blocks from the other post.